# Windows 10 will not install update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

I recently restarted my computer and got a notification that Windows was installing an update, which stalled on 100%, meaning I had to manually force the restart to continue. After the computer booted back up, I got a message saying that Windows could not install updates.

I've tried restarting since then, but Windows no-longer even attempts to install the update. I am still getting notifications from Windows periodically, telling me an update failed. When I click on the failed update notification it merely shows me a list of previously installed updates, but not the failed installation.

The last entry shown is:

```
Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2, 2016 x64 Edition - March 2017 (KB890830)
```

How do I clear the failed update and force Windows to update again? It would also be useful to find out what update Windows attempted to install. Is there a log with this info, perhaps?

Comment: last update for 1607 is KB4013429. Get it from catalog and install the MSU: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4013429 does this work? if not, copy the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS to desktop, zip it and share the zip

Comment: Are you on 1607 (run `winver` to check)? I had many problems with the 1607 upgrade, not solved until I installed from the ISO over the top of the previous 1511 version.

Comment: Yeah, on 1607. The 'apply update' thing seems to have gone from the power option now, though (it was there when I booted up the last time, but seems to have disappeared while I've been using the machine) so does that mean Windows has sorted it out somehow? I've downloaded KB4013429 and I'm gonna apply it once I've finished off a few bits and pieces I have going on right now.

Comment: All sorted and working now thanks to magicandre. Intrigued by whoever left the downvote. Apparently there is something someone thinks utterly heinous about this question... or perhaps they just hadn't had their coffee fix this morning.

Comment: In that case @magicandre1981 - post an answer please.

Comment: It's difficult to explain how to install an update when you don't identify which update failed.

Comment: @Ramhound I noted in my question my attempts to find the name of the failed update, listed the last successful update, and asked for assistance in finding the update log likely to contain details on the failed update.

Comment: Up votes are worth a lot more than down votes. An occasional down vote is a normal part of the process.

Comment: @RailsKiddie - You never provided the information from winver within the body of your question.  I could tell based on the build your using which patch failed.  I can't determine that from the information you provided in your question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the automatic setup via Windows Update fails, get the MSU for KB4013429 (March 2017 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 V1607) on your own from the [Update catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4013429).

Double click on the MSU to install the update.

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION FOUND to cumulative update KB4013429. Tried everything many times over three days: repairing system files, refreshing components from ISO, stand-alone update, etc. etc. and still the message: "failed to update..undoing changes...".

Problem solved by downloading script to reset Windows Update: "resetWUeng.cmd" from this link:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc

System successfully upgraded from 10.14393.693 to 10.14393.953 - The only thing that worked for me !!!