# Windows Update 'Check for updates' does nothing

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

My Windows 10 hasn't been updated for a while. When I open Windows Update, I see the following text:

`Your device is at risk because it's out of date and missing important security and quality updates. Let's get you back on track so Windows can run more securely. Select this button to get going: Check for updates`

[image: Update status]

When I click `Check for updates`, nothing happens. Checking for updates displays for around two seconds, then I see the original message again.

**What I have unsuccesfully tried so far:**

- Windows Update troubleshooter. (Did not find any problems.)
- Download the most recent Servicing Stack Update (SSU) from the Microsoft Update Catalog. (Installation failed.)
- Fix Windows file corruption by running `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` and `sfc /scannow`. (Did not find any problems.)
- The accepted answer in [Can I invoke Windows Update from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/462425/can-i-invoke-windows-update-from-the-command-line). (The commands `Get-WindowsUpdate` and `Install-WindowsUpdate` do nothing for me).

I have Windows 10 Education Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.98). Latest successful system update is `Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based Systems (KB4058043)` installed on `2017-12-17`. Curiously, things like `Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool` and `Security Update for Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10` still update just fine through Windows Update. But Windows itself refuses to update.

How do I get Windows Update working?

Edit:
[Output of `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`](https://pastebin.com/YdQvHuBW)

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but it would help the potential contributors if you provided a bit more information regarding which version of Windows 10 you *are* running:  Home or Pro, etc.  Also, try executing Start > Run, type `winver` and hit `Enter`.  That will provide us with the OS version number and build number.

Comment: @Run5k Thanks, I've added those.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Windows updates break for me I run my nifty script, please give it a try. You will need to run it as an administrator:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Simple Script to Reset / Clear Windows Update
echo.
PAUSE
echo.
attrib -h -r -s %windir%\system32\catroot2
attrib -h -r -s %windir%\system32\catroot2\*.*
net stop wuauserv
net stop CryptSvc
net stop BITS
ren %windir%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.old
ren %windir%\SoftwareDistribution sold.old
ren "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\application data\Microsoft\Network\downloader" downloader.old
net Start BITS
net start CryptSvc
net start wuauserv
echo.
echo Task completed successfully...
echo.
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. Unfortunately it did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Drat, could you open the event viewer and check the Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > WindowsUpdateClient and add any relevant looking logs to your question?

Comment: When all else fails, I've downloaded the Windows ISO and installed/repaired from USB flash drive. Often, *repair* works, but I make a disk image beforehand because files *do* get damaged.

Comment: @Hugo Good suggestion, under `Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient/Operational` I found `Windows Update successfully found 0 updates.` which gets logged whenever I check for updates. I got a more detailed log (link in original post) by running `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`, although I didn't notice anything directly useful in there myself.

Comment: I would manually download the current cumulative patch and install that.

Comment: @Ramhound I installed `2018-03 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based Systems (KB4090913)` from `catalog.update.microsoft.com`. Check for updates now says my device is up to date. You could post that as an answer, the keyword `cumulative` was very helpful.

Comment: @Steve it was already [suggested way ago to use catalog page to get MSU files if WU fails](https://superuser.com/a/1189736/174557)

Comment: @Steve You should have tried that before you asked the question